# Altair plot is cut off at top

Tags: python, data-visualization, altair

I am using the code

```
alt.data_transformers.disable_max_rows()
alt.renderers.enable('altair_viewer')

alt.Chart(res_fake).mark_circle(size=50).encode(
    x='gwp',
    y='eval_val',
    fill='wF',
    row='eval_name',
    column='name'
).properties(
   height=150, width=500
).resolve_scale(
    x='independent',
    y='independent'
)
```

to produce an altair image, the top panels are cut off. I am not able to scroll up:

[image]

When I zoom out (by a lot) all my facet panels are displayed. However, they are not displayed if I scroll. Why not?

I am using this (fake) data - here in a CSV-format:

```
eval_val,eval_name,gwp,wF,name
0.8018070414818939,-8239627666060592049,0.47145738473041443,M,f
0.7367232615321743,-8239627666060592049,0.22562470294190218,M,R
0.3938556306116078,-8239627666060592049,0.6665142486455571,m,R
0.07517139370864345,-8239627666060592049,0.23541819961894073,K,R
0.7052544914470192,-8239627666060592049,0.07651898340607788,K,f
0.9719802737558002,-8239627666060592049,0.40057271724096677,m,f
0.026758387962984354,-8239627666060592049,0.25399750661742926,T,R
0.06337476779609952,-8239627666060592049,0.3317841738148253,T,f
0.015755734764964502,-559632761220026298,0.41690734221812065,M,f
0.3000005699109288,-559632761220026298,0.06548917115095132,M,R
0.06398444608204723,-559632761220026298,0.15647758223365626,m,R
0.7428717972324411,-559632761220026298,0.028970289817533024,K,R
0.3688361341046422,-559632761220026298,0.8429619832472521,K,f
0.22083517276744413,-559632761220026298,0.34493768436066663,m,f
0.7938672174156153,-559632761220026298,0.015461058999543753,T,R
0.3020704695833929,-559632761220026298,0.6271773890232436,T,f
0.28491021185991383,1700818862982138616,0.31948620826629126,M,f
0.9402258466900844,1700818862982138616,0.4255614556148788,M,R
0.34890903629758097,1700818862982138616,0.3033429891594078,m,R
0.7076907044980314,1700818862982138616,0.14286501716147415,K,R
0.241852357191505,1700818862982138616,0.9252612435609489,K,f
0.29074517745380646,1700818862982138616,0.8562189096306039,m,f
0.44515848147431714,1700818862982138616,0.008055175465267128,T,R
0.21210213567967906,1700818862982138616,0.9960407579598495,T,f
0.49388328568236384,-6477347714658111910,0.557857415711619,M,f
0.21408538713134517,-6477347714658111910,0.21550271622415207,M,R
0.8881240997258868,-6477347714658111910,0.2106168112428638,m,R
0.910525281992466,-6477347714658111910,0.5967880862034386,K,R
0.6449496538698186,-6477347714658111910,0.37574425178429716,K,f
0.6413581952325688,-6477347714658111910,0.6795782238874866,m,f
0.3149381707769431,-6477347714658111910,0.9357944968565332,T,R
0.5485012611360953,-6477347714658111910,0.5421851794738894,T,f
0.47859217539193566,4069926770395472028,0.5079279503567289,M,f
0.2897004075210511,4069926770395472028,0.22602691228798466,M,R
0.30208237096499535,4069926770395472028,0.5805765158273514,m,R
0.2070846191228325,4069926770395472028,0.4589858780270598,K,R
0.3003857228260971,4069926770395472028,0.8307841270779706,K,f
0.22050824333910168,4069926770395472028,0.5006045612261167,m,f
0.5280121592116018,4069926770395472028,0.7190011910843657,T,R
0.9647569114264541,4069926770395472028,0.17512431624018565,T,f
0.9710075545877016,-8628858432231373027,0.2233139382261855,M,f
0.9514213384780086,-8628858432231373027,0.22305028452966968,M,R
0.8667831273522613,-8628858432231373027,0.6593069490547764,m,R
0.9343584158854514,-8628858432231373027,0.8860114964632293,K,R
0.8373414354082518,-8628858432231373027,0.03898492382365992,K,f
0.6549234133804548,-8628858432231373027,0.09012854667334746,m,f
0.7676053537075722,-8628858432231373027,0.23339262930994742,T,R
0.5058549696584528,-8628858432231373027,0.8371824262071537,T,f
0.8087398291174301,5920082728593464157,0.30114579417613674,M,f
0.07763272301227009,5920082728593464157,0.19508928747610732,M,R
0.5305489020529206,5920082728593464157,0.20458772063848718,m,R
0.4751656195711609,5920082728593464157,0.34711759265923803,K,R
0.44456128686023577,5920082728593464157,0.26485024392828493,K,f
0.831568434105014,5920082728593464157,0.2105262112541222,m,f
0.8717662568962934,5920082728593464157,0.0449936613292683,T,R
0.9220374278291483,5920082728593464157,0.18158403908008025,T,f
0.5230959033443936,-3572783456420383499,0.23828093458210464,M,f
0.36627872677068996,-3572783456420383499,0.3920382355826758,M,R
0.3745126519858636,-3572783456420383499,0.14336290614885638,m,R
0.2527394576590427,-3572783456420383499,0.31908401653987173,K,R
0.7564817996870457,-3572783456420383499,0.07396980552198285,K,f
0.030404057812821517,-3572783456420383499,0.4524769464814984,m,f
0.13903400047072556,-3572783456420383499,0.6887373007309381,T,R
0.3170765378016275,-3572783456420383499,0.4279899949642382,T,f
0.6046566365281667,-8512446642115702610,0.23401551554028766,M,f
0.7755285766694002,-8512446642115702610,0.043637167376038954,M,R
0.6785706952141253,-8512446642115702610,0.3096961424214053,m,R
0.8540282092170921,-8512446642115702610,0.05353808738282939,K,R
0.0004338228275557743,-8512446642115702610,0.4080448648052145,K,f
0.00633265010576578,-8512446642115702610,0.04877479334726853,m,f
0.3510589264867636,-8512446642115702610,0.8003649055855244,T,R
0.5736996331993465,-8512446642115702610,0.3512180475740425,T,f
0.9575875831732106,-1521238857432044020,0.31980168808367804,M,f
0.08929009064366555,-1521238857432044020,0.425530625278403,M,R
0.722656499017316,-1521238857432044020,0.9423949995494046,m,R
0.03428888397144281,-1521238857432044020,0.7937694940226406,K,R
0.006182912262933327,-1521238857432044020,0.4630168353584919,K,f
0.7939945164577773,-1521238857432044020,0.380462460715454,m,f
0.24880486658377232,-1521238857432044020,0.23101096635623852,T,R
0.8725519214887459,-1521238857432044020,0.908249282858777,T,f
0.728766743950487,9192879028953115584,0.22448711975102775,M,f
0.8481191714449537,9192879028953115584,0.5629447669001315,M,R
0.0728846461004814,9192879028953115584,0.5399270530508733,m,R
0.6362348602494637,9192879028953115584,0.33488156106569644,K,R
0.018939130583278785,9192879028953115584,0.20992375797835872,K,f
0.4123382282421949,9192879028953115584,0.7566235161660171,m,f
0.8341576814877727,9192879028953115584,0.5516962620282976,T,R
0.1679253108831914,9192879028953115584,0.14230366082337664,T,f
0.05922932153436444,9194802079104312354,0.8563940046489156,M,f
0.8579448379155671,9194802079104312354,0.4707432539936841,M,R
0.7636656525861916,9194802079104312354,0.7750913800759516,m,R
0.559101707195229,9194802079104312354,0.34631383996789034,K,R
0.9314119220000752,9194802079104312354,0.768584718991535,K,f
0.9322348897302901,9194802079104312354,0.17149145223322426,m,f
0.6501039108328825,9194802079104312354,0.1634841006522736,T,R
0.09134108855649348,9194802079104312354,0.24210144949747958,T,f
0.25151400150335435,2860116794196427213,0.13940373514661708,M,f
0.3788954010389003,2860116794196427213,0.13389085392350142,M,R
0.6474924625410227,2860116794196427213,0.47597753787292296,m,R
0.9724329250481943,2860116794196427213,0.6994051164660883,K,R
0.4839164736247935,2860116794196427213,0.4055799090375731,K,f
0.8854714569612795,2860116794196427213,0.06837375159324854,m,f
0.6319575154359726,2860116794196427213,0.028486400107122445,T,R
0.04524561222576484,2860116794196427213,0.7497791383427207,T,f
0.07033839157392696,-8708856447242747197,0.6354127844658325,M,f
0.6516636085600679,-8708856447242747197,0.015662374828279813,M,R
0.7227062667003826,-8708856447242747197,0.8219383751794241,m,R
0.4117873263220111,-8708856447242747197,0.18358635861961103,K,R
0.5229230424035316,-8708856447242747197,0.9790475194507113,K,f
0.07825288591332669,-8708856447242747197,0.4021323029657268,m,f
0.3928647588144507,-8708856447242747197,0.3186248197296737,T,R
0.8110572905331423,-8708856447242747197,0.9561175918421408,T,f
```

I am using the Brave browser here (which is based on Chrome) on Linux Kubuntu 20.04 - but I am not sure whether that is relevant.

Comment: If you think it could be browser (or addon) based, it would be good to try another browser or two. If that doesn't work could you create an example with the vega sample datasets in the documentation or share a minimal complete code example together with your data so that we can try to reproduce?

Comment: @joelostblom: I tried also Chrome. In both cases I do not use addons. I added some information and example data in the question. Tell me if something is still missing.

Comment: It seems like something is up with the `.show()` and `.serve()` methods that cause this behavior with the row facets and I can see it on my end also. Potentially it is a problem with `altair_viewer`, so I would open a bug report either there or in the main Altair repo.  If you save the chart to an HTML file and open the HTML file in the browser it works fine as doe salso viewing the vegaspec in the vegaeditor or the chart in a jupyter notebook.Do you need to use show/serve or how are you trying to open the chart?

Comment: @joelostblom: I *am* using the altair viewer - you are right. I was just using `alt.renderers.enable('altair_viewer')` and then just press enter for the chart object. I guess this is basically `show`? I am not necessarily using Jupyter - mostly using PyCharm. That is why I am using the altair viewer.

Comment: Issue opened here https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/2441

Answer (score 1):

Since Altair 5.3, the functionality of Altair Viewer is now available in Altair via the [vl-convert](https://github.com/vega/vl-convert) package instead. See [the docs on how to use the browser renderer](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/display_frontends.html#browser-renderer) to display charts via `.show()`, and the PR https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/pull/3379 for more details. The new approach does not have the issue with charts being clipped.